# How do I get FFMPEG to make make multiple recordings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I need to find a way to get ffmpeg to start recording again after the duration expires, so I can break the files up into more manageable chunks. Unfortunately, the only funcion I've found is the ability to limit the amount of time it records before terminating, with nothing about how to get it to keep recording in the next file afterwards. is ther a function to do this?

```
for(i = 0; i < streamsRepository.streams.length; i++) {
    var obj  = streamsRepository.streams[i];
    findTheRightSave();
    console.log('Channel '+obj.key+' is Recording');

    fmpeg(obj.url)
    .duration('1:00')
    .format('mp3')
      .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.error(err);
        console.error(stdout);
        console.error(stderr)
      })

        .save('/home/spencer/recorder/audio/'+obj.key+'/Recording-'+numRecordings+'.mp3');
        numRecordings=1;
}
```

Comment: is there a 'done' event when ffmpeg finishes?

Comment: You mean on ('end',)? How can I get the ffmpeg called recursively?

Comment: could be 'end', 'done', 'complete', some event that fires when ffmpeg finishes ... actaully, I just realised that wont help with the way you're doing this (I'm assuming node.js with some ffmpeg library?)

Comment: Yeah Nodejs with fluent-ffmpeg

Comment: I take it obj.url is an actual URL. Is it something you could read by other means (i.e. read it within node, not using external program), then you can buffer it up, spitting out chunks as you please, and now nodejs controlls the starting **and stopping** of ffmpeg. I take it also that ffmpeg is transcoding the input?

Comment: what if you declare a function `record()` that will call `ffmpeg()` and call it back in the `end` event of transcoding?

Comment: Kaiido: infinitely recursive loop until it exceeded to maximum call stack

Answer (score 0):

Us the following pparameters to ffmpeg (not sure how you can do it with fluent-ffmpeg)

```
-f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 60 outputfile_%d.mp3
```

I don't know what ANY of those parameters mean, but that's a start

jsut tested here

```
ffmpeg -i "Sovereign Quarter.mp3" -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 60 sq%d.mp3
```

and got 4 x 1 minute files and 1 x 51 second file - original file length was 4:51, so looks like there was a way ffmpeg could do it after all - though

Hope you have better luck figuring out how to add those options in fluent-ffmpeg than I did. That's why I stopped using fluent-ffmpeg, I could never figure out how to add arbitrary (valid) options to the process

Comment: So wait, does this mean I'd need to introduce something to read a file from the stdout file, like icescast, instead of just being able to set the file to output like I've been doing? It seems like there would be a simpler solution than this...

Comment: I've checked but I can't find anything. I assume there is a way to do it.

Comment: What is the use of the 1 in that output? I can enter all of these through .outputOption but for some reason the 1 is consistently registering as being unable to find a suitable output function.

Comment: it's a value for -reset_timestamps parameter

Comment: Okay, but it still throws up the error [NULL @ 0x2219240] Unable to find a suitable output format for '1'
1: Invalid argument

Comment: try without the -reset_timestamps 1

Comment: That just gives me 

  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

Comment: And if I take out -f, it works fine, but the actual segmenting doesn't occur, and I'm just left with an expanding file.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work, but for some reason its not actually segmenting, its just recording as usual with no breaks and no splitting up into multiple files.

Comment: Is segment really supposed to be wit a "-"? Cause it eems like thats whats cuasing it to not actualy segment. Of course, adding that means it won't recognise segment.

Comment: segment ISN'T with a "-" in the answer? here it is again ... `-f  segment  -reset_timestamps  1  -segment_time  60` ... tested and works fine on local files, but not on 'streams'

Comment: I said I **TESTED** on local files but not on streams - I have no idea if it works or not on streams as I do not have a stream to check with